# - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

Tags: java, syntax-error

I've spent a couple hours just trying to solve this syntax error but it's defeating me in every way. I tried putting closing brackets at the end, in between various blocks but nothing would work. This is for a class assignment, it's pretty much finished but this error is keeping me from actually submitting it.

```
public class Coffee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Default Constructor 
        public Coffee() {
            this.sugar = 0.0;
            this.milk = 0;
            this.currentlyHot = false;

        }  

        //Instance Variables        
        private double sugar;
        private int milk;
        private boolean currentlyHot; // hot
        private int size;

        // Constructor        
        public Coffee (double id, int dairy, boolean temp) {
            this.sugar = id;
            this.milk = dairy;
            this.currentlyHot = temp;        
        }

        // (setter)
        public void setSugar(double id) {
            sugar = id;
        }
        public void setMilk(int dairy) {
            milk = dairy;
        }       
        public void setSize(boolean temp) {
            currentlyHot = temp;
        }

        public void setHeat(boolean isHot) {
            this.currentlyHot = isHot;
        }

        //(getter)  
        public double getSugar() {
            return this.sugar;
        }

        public int getMilk() {
            return this.milk;
        }

        public boolean checkcurrentlyHot() {
            return this.currentlyHot;
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return this.size;
        }

        // Method to display data
        public void display() {
            System.out.println("You have " + sugar + " sugar in your cup");
            System.out.println("You have " + getMilk() + " in your coffee");
            System.out.println("That's a " + getSize() + " ounce cup");
            System.out.println("Is the cup hot? " + checkcurrentlyHot());            


        }

    }
```

Comment: Insert a '}' at the end.

Comment: Your code miss the closing brackets of the class try adding closing brackes and the end

Comment: what is the dangling  `    ;` ?

Comment: remove `;`......

Comment: Why do you have a constructor _inside_ your `main`?  That makes no sense.  You shouldn't be trying to nest one method inside another like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have your constructor and other code in your `main` menthod

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Default Constructor 
    public Coffee() {   // move this code
    ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Your probably want to have your `main` as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Coffee c = new Coffee ();  // or use the other constructor
      c.display ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods and variables are declared in main(), it's not possible in Java. Take it out of main, It will work.

```
class Coffee {

      public Coffee() {
          this.sugar = 0.0;
          this.milk = 0;
          this.currentlyHot = false;

      }  

      //Instance Variables        
      private double sugar;
      private int milk;
      private boolean currentlyHot; // hot
      private int size;

      // Constructor        
      public Coffee (double id, int dairy, boolean temp) {
          this.sugar = id;
          this.milk = dairy;
          this.currentlyHot = temp;        
      }

      // (setter)
      public void setSugar(double id) {
          sugar = id;
      }
      public void setMilk(int dairy) {
          milk = dairy;
      }       
      public void setSize(boolean temp) {
          currentlyHot = temp;
      }

      public void setHeat(boolean isHot) {
          this.currentlyHot = isHot;
      }

      //(getter)  
      public double getSugar() {
          return this.sugar;
      }

      public int getMilk() {
          return this.milk;
      }

      public boolean checkcurrentlyHot() {
          return this.currentlyHot;
      }

      public int getSize() {
          return this.size;
      }

      // Method to display data
      public void display() {
          System.out.println("You have " + sugar + " sugar in your cup");
          System.out.println("You have " + getMilk() + " in your coffee");
          System.out.println("That's a " + getSize() + " ounce cup");
          System.out.println("Is the cup hot? " + checkcurrentlyHot());            


      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Default Constructor 


    }
}
```

Comment: why need `;` ??

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was part of original post, i think you missed it. I am updating same in post.

Answer (score 0):

You have put everything in the main method. The constructor, the property declaration, the method declaration. Also there is a missing end brace at the end. Move the constructor, variable and method declaration out of the main method.